# Two-dimensional array with .Add in C#

Tags: c#, collections

I need to store a collection of `Point` pairs, but don't want to use plain C# arrays to be bound to use of iterators. Which is the easiest way (except using `KeyValuePair<Point,Point>`) to have such an two dimensional collection at hand with being able to `.Add(Point, Point)` to it?

Comment: What about making new class to store pairs? And then put instances of this class into collection?

Comment: Maybe `List<Tuple<Point, Point>>`

Comment: Create your own List of Tuple<Point, Point> and override the Add method so you do not neet to initialise a new Tuple. MyList.Add(point a, point b) { }

Comment: I like Perlnika's idea more than using Tuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Point,Point` is *not* a key-value pair, it's a `Tuple<Point,Point>`. You can create a `List<Tuple<Point,Point>>` or whatever fits your needs.

However, you should keep something in mind - a `Tuple` is an immutable structure - you can't change it's elements to point to other `Point` objects (however, if the `Point` object itself is mutable, you could mutate the `Point`). If you need to be able to change elements from this list to point to other points, create your own class to hold these.

Answer (score 4):

Subclass `List<Tuple<Point,Point>>` and create an overload of .Add with two Point parameters.

```
public class MyCollection : List<Tuple<Point, Point>>
{
    public void Add(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        this.Add(Tuple.Create(p1, p2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

will `List<Tuple<int,int>>` you help?

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<Point, Point>>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx

Comment: +1 for being the only person to use `IEnumerable` over `List`. It could have been more specific to the example by using `Point` instead of leaving the generic type parameters though.